# Take slice through surf plot of multiple spheres and find volume of all spheres dissected

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, geometry, volume

I have a 3d sample (ice) which I am filling with spheres (air bubbles) until it is a known density and plotting using bubbleplot3 from the file exchange ( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8231-bubbleplot3/content/bubbleplot3.m ). The function I'm using and sample input is below and the plot that is produced is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8npa.png).

[image]

What I want to be able to do is take a slice through this sample and find the volume of spheres that would be exposed to the surface if this is done. (I need to calculate the porosity of the sample, so I'm interested in how much liquid would be able to seep into the sample if it were cut).

I've tried a few things like populating a large logical 3d matrix with 'air or ice' values but it just gets too big.

Any ideas welcome.

Cheers

```
sphere_count(1,2,4,0.025,0.885)

function [ s ] = sphere_count( x,y,z,b_d,d )
%sphere_count Summary of this function goes here
%   x,y,z = dimensions of ice sample, b_d is bubble diameter, d is ice
%   sample density
sample_vol = x*y*z;
air_pc = 1-(d./0.917);
air_vol = sample_vol*air_pc;
sphere_vol = 4*pi*((b_d/10)./2)^2;
number_of_spheres = floor(air_vol/sphere_vol);
P = [(x.*rand(1,1)),(y.*rand(1,1)),(z.*rand(1,1))];
k = 1;
while k < number_of_spheres
    P1 = [(x.*rand(1,1)),(y.*rand(1,1)),(z.*rand(1,1))]; % Make new co-ords
    D = pdist2(P1,P,'euclidean'); % calculate distance between
    if D>(b_d/2) % test maximum distance
        P=[P;P1];  %#ok<*AGROW> % concat
        k=k+1;
    end
end
x=P(:,1);y=P(:,2);z=P(:,3); 
a = 0.02; % Variance
b = b_d; % Mean
R = a.*randn(numel(P(:,1)),1) + b;
bubbleplot3(x,y,z,R);
```

Comment: Well slicing through a plot seems as if it would be cumbersome. I could think of a number of walk arounds, but I am not completely sure if you want a nice looking picture or a numerical answer here.

Comment: I don't want a nice plot, just a numerical answer. I guess I'd like to be able to find out the volume of the spheres dissected and the location within those spheres that my 'slice' would hit. Ultimately if two spheres are overlapping, it would be amazing to be able to combine the volumes of both the dissected sphere and the sphere it is 'connected' to. Although I don't have a clue how to begin doing that.

Comment: It is an interesting problem. I think that the easiest way is to just define a set of points defininge each sphere through that slice as polygons. Then calculate the union of the polygons. Then you should be able to sum the area of the "union polygons". The part of finding the union of polygons is cumbersome as well. If you have **mapping toolbox** you can do it with `polybool`. Else I would recommend scanning the internet for some function. There is a mexfunction called polygon clipper on mathworks stack exchange, I think that one does what you want.

Comment: "I think that the easiest way is to just define a set of points defininge each sphere through that slice as polygons" How would you go about doing that?

Comment: You have the center and the radius (I hope). Then just go on and do it, `x = r*cos(phi)*sin(theta); y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta); z = r*cos(theta)`. Just calculate `theta` and let `phi` be a vector from 0 to 2pi, np.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "defining each sphere" of course. What I mean is that you define it like a polygon. You may of course find each intersecting sphere and the intersecting area as well, but that does not seem easier. However this would allow you to calculate the area each spheres intersection and then remove the intersecting area.

Comment: Are you looking for an arbitrary slice, or would an average suffice? For example, if you knew the average volume that a random slice would expose, would that answer your question? Specific slices are hard, and I don't know how to do it, but I can give you the average answer right now.

Comment: average may actually be more useful.